# Adjusting Image Height in Single Table Element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the image size in a table. There are two images side by side. I need the one on the left to be roughly 50% the size of the one to the right.

How would I do this? When I try adding a height element to anywhere in the code, it does not show up, either height="some number" or height="some number %". I can bring the image out of the table but then things start looking messy.

Code pasted below and any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
<table class="rspnsv" width="620" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" border-spacing="0" border-collapse="collapse">
        <tbody class="rspnsv" width="620" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" border-spacing="0" border-collapse="collapse">
            <td class="rspnsv" width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" border="0" border-spacing="0" border-collapse="collapse">
                <img class="picture" width="300" src="edm/2.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="rspnsv" width="20" height="20" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" border="0" border-spacing="0" border-collapse="collapse"></td>
            <td class="rspnsv" width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" border="0" border-spacing="0" border-collapse="collapse">
                <img class="picture" width="300" src="edm/3.jpg">
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: please add your code as minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m). Do the images have the same aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

If you say the left picture should be 50% of the size of the right one, that means that the right picture has twice the size.

You can achieve that either with flexbox or css-grid. The css-grid approach is to make a 3 column grid. the left pciture spans 1 column while the right spans 2 columns and 2 rows and as such will be twice the size.

```css
.image-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.image-grid img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-grid :nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="image-grid">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0736.jpg">
</section>
```

the flexbox approach is easier and has a better compability with IE. There you size the first image simply as 33% width and the right image as 66% width. To not have the smaller image aligned to the vertical center, you can use: `align-self: flex-start;`.

```css
.image-grid {
  display: flex;
}

.image-grid img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.image-grid :nth-child(1) {
  width: 33.33%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.image-grid :nth-child(2) {
  width: 66.66%;
}
```

```html
<section class="image-grid">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0736.jpg">
</section>
```